# Reinstall python with modules

Tags: python

I will format my pc and i would like to somehow collect all the python modules that i have currently and package them (zip or rar etc) / or create an index file of them, so that when i'm done formatting the pc i can reinstall them all in one go, either by using the package/or by using the index created to pip install them all in a batch.

Is there any python module that allows to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pip

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

This will save the names of all your installed python modules to a file called *requirements.txt*.

Then when you want to install them again run the following command.

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Using a package manager like this is good practice to get into, especially if you use a code repository, so you dont upload all the dependencies to the repo.

If you are not already doing so, its a good idea to use a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) for your python projects. 
This will create a unique python environment for each of your projects, keeping each project self contained.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - `pip`. Using `pip freeze` will give you the list of all the installed modules. Next all you need to do is to install all that modules by running `pip install -r your_file_with_modules_list`.